# Oracle query to Postgress query change ERROR

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

We are in progress to move our db to Postgres from Orcale.

There is this Oracle query (changed verbiage for privacy concerns):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT somedata.* FROM SNSN.SMS_TXN_SOMEDATA somedata 
    WHERE ((car= 'tesla' OR car = 'teslaX' OR car = 'teslaY') OR (buyer= 'john' OR buyer = 'rony' OR jim = 'sam')) 
    AND code = :code 
    ORDER BY somedata.datetime) 
    WHERE LIMIT :num
```

When I hit the endpoint I get this error

> ERROR: argument of LIMIT must be type bigint, not type character varying

What would be a suitable/alternative variable to bind this. What can I use instead of variables :code and :num.

Comment: Without seeing the code you use to bind `num` it isn't possible to answer your question. Presumably you're binding it to a `String`, instead of a numeric data type.

Comment: The query as show will result in a completely different error. `WHERE LIMIT ..` is invalid  - you need to remove that WHERE keyword. And the derived table requires an alias in Postgres.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried without the WHERE but still get the same above error. What do you mean the derived table requires an alias? Could you please let me know?